# How do you handle letters not in typical english when using Jetson.utils.cudaFont.OverlayText() function?

Tags: python, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am trying to make a program that detects objects then translates the object name into Danish, but when overlaying the text for the translation on the image itself, the letters not found in english, such as Æ, Ø, and Å, always show up terribly (such as fængsel showing up as fÃ|ngsel). In the command line, I am printing out the text that I'm putting into the parameter of the function and it comes out fine on the command prompt but bad when overlaid on the image.

I am using python 3 and have the Nvidia Jetson nano.

This is the line that is overlaying incorrect text on the image.

```
font.OverlayText(img, width, height, "{:05.2f}% {:s}".format(confidence * 100, translateText(class_desc, "da")), 5, 5, font.White, font.Gray40)
```

translateText() is a seperate function that works in which you input the text and language to translate to and it returns a string which I have checked is correct

and font is defined as

```
font = jetson.utils.cudaFont()
```

Comment: Does the function support UTF-8? Sounds like a strange decoding error.

Comment: Did you have the chance to test my answer? I don't have a Jetson nano so it's all theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

You are feeding `cudafont` with UTF-8 encoded text. Looking at [the source](https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-utils/blob/master/cuda/cudaFont.cu), there seems to be *nothing* that handles UTF-8 – or even, if I am seeing it right, nothing that re-encodes *anything* from the natural glyph order in the font to a regular encoding:

```c
char c = str[n];
if( c < FirstGlyph || c > LastGlyph )
    continue;

c -= FirstGlyph;
... now c will hold glyph data for a character
```

(from the function `int4 cudaFont::TextExtents`)

#### That means that this library is *severely crippled* in its character handling.

A *glyph*, in the following context, only means "a certain image that can be associated with an existing characters or combination of characters (i.e., a ligature "ﬁ" is a single glyph that represents the two characters "f" and "i"). A font also must define an *encoding* (built-in, by a certain convention such as PostScript Type 1 fonts, or, in the case of a TrueType/OpenType fonts, defined in their `cmap` table) to associate character codes with their correct glyphs.

CUDA's default fonts DejaVu Sans and DejaVu Sans Mono are TrueType fonts and do contain a `cmap` table, so their glyphs can physically be in any random order – it's up to the font designer's discretion. A font may list all of its A glyphs first, then all its B glyphs, and so on, or be in literally any order. If the font contains an encoding table for Latin-1, the table will translate between the *character code* for `A` and the font's *glyph position* for the appropriate glyph. If that same font also contains a wildly different encoding, such as EBCDIC, its own code for `A` (which is not based on ASCII and therefore not "the usual" 0x41, but 0xC1) will still point to the same `A` *glyph* in the font.

What `cudafont` does is something entirely else. It *assumes* that the glyphs for *at least* basic ASCII appear in exactly that order, starting from the very first glyph in a font. It means that you cannot use any other glyph order than the one that has been imposed by the designer of the font. Also, because `cudafont` limits character codes to 8 bits only, you cannot access any of the 6,107 (DejaVu Sans) and 3,309 (DejaVu Sans Mono) characters, except those in the range before ASCII code 256.

I briefly glanced over the glyph set and it appears to me that they are in *Unicode order*. Now, in a lucky stroke (for `cudafont`s programmers), that indeed means that the first 95 characters are in ASCII order.

Unfortunately for *you*, my Western European reader (typically not interested in anything beyond Latin-1's borders) – the next still follow the common [ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) order *but*, per convention, the range from 0x7F to 0x9F is missing. In Unicode Latin-1 Supplement, which is based on the original Latin-1, these codes represent [control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) and do not have a glyph representation.

It still means you cannot feed Python's default UTF-8 encoded strings into it, but apart from plain ASCII you *also* cannot instruct Python to encode your text to Latin-1. Python can encode it alright:

```py
text = 'fængsel'
print (text)
print (text.encode('latin-1'))

fængsel
b'f\xe6ngsel'
```

but due to that missing range, a character is displayed that appears only 33 glyphs further in the list: `ć`.

Solution: there are 33 characters missing in between, and so you can adjust your (now) *binary* string contents to match the *physical* glyph order again:

```py
btext = bytes([c if c <= 0x7f else c-33 for c in text.encode('latin-1')])
print (btext)

b'f\xc5ngsel'
```

and *that* string should (theoretically) finally render your `fængsel`.

Any hypothetical user that wants to access glyphs beyond the range of this fix are out of luck until `cudafont` gets updated to (a) properly *use* a font's encoding, and (b) support the full Unicode range instead of `char`s only. At least it gets a brief mention in `stb_truetype.h`:

> > //   Todo:
> >     //        non-MS cmaps

Comment: Thank you for your helpful information. I didn't bring it home over the weekend but I'll definitely try out your solution when I get back and update you

Comment: Tried it out and it gave me this error: [cuda]  cudaOverlayText<float4>( mFontMapGPU, maxGlyphSize, mFontMapWidth, ((GlyphCommand*)mCommandGPU) + mCmdIndex, numCommands, color, image, image, width, height)
[cuda]     invalid configuration argument (error 9) (hex 0x09)
[cuda]     /home/drjbishops/jetson-inference/utils/cuda/cudaFont.cu:539                      And then no text showed up overlaying the image. I have a backup solution where I don't use the real letters (ae for æ), so no worries but thanks for your help. It seems cudafont simply isn't prepared to handle such letters yet.